# What is causing this span element to behave differently in Firefox than Chrome?

Tags: html, css

So the Spanish sentence being displayed wraps around to 2 lines and I need to align the "expresar" word with the first letter of the sentence (not the question mark).

For the CSS #1 and corresponding HTML #1 code, this works in Chrome but not in Firefox (at least when testing on Linux with Chrome 39.0 and Firefox 34.0).

But when I change to CSS #2 and corresponding HTML #2, the alignment I want works correctly.  Why does it work differently in Firefox than Chrome?  And how in the future can I figure out these subtle differences?

**CSS #1**

```
html[lang="es-MX"] #faq-list h3 .text-align .text-align-part {
        margin-left: 8px; }
```

**HTML #1**

```
<div class='text-align'>
  ¿A quién puedo contactar en Stan para más información sobre sujetos humanos en una investigación o para
  <span class='text-align-part'>
    expresar una inquietud o queja?
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS #2**

```
html[lang="es-MX"] #faq-list h3 .text-align .text-align-part {
        margin-left: 8px;
        display: inline-block; }
```

**HTML #2**

```
<div class='text-align'>
      ¿A quién puedo contactar en Stan para más información sobre sujetos humanos en una investigación o para
    <div class='text-align-part'>
        expresar una inquietud o queja?
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: To prevent future browser incompatibilities you could use a library that normalizes or resets the CSS styles. Personally I like to work with normalize: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ ...  You can see if that will cure your problems. Place it as top CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that - right now I've been using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ at the top of the file.  I wonder if normalizing is really the issue?  I don't know enough about CSS yet to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the it's not aligned in both browsers is likely because of the way the browsers handle fonts. For example, the font on my portfolio renders really thin on Safari, more crisp on Firefox, but the correct size (but more blurry) on Chrome.

Now to answer your question, the best way to handle this is probably to kill the `margin-left` and add a blank space in front of the second line using `&nbsp;`

So your HTML #1 would look like:

```
<div class='text-align'>
    ¿A quién puedo contactar en Stan para más información sobre sujetos humanos en una investigación o para
    <span class='text-align-part'>
        &nbsp;expresar una inquietud o queja?
    </span>
</div>
```